# How to store NTP time format into MySQL

Tags: mysql

1) I have a CSV file which contains data, one of the field is date time in NTP format: hour, minutes, seconds, microseconds, time_zone, day, month, day_of_month, year. example (14:06:18.369 gmt Wed May 15 2013). How can i store this into MySQL? my only options are DATETIME,DATE,TIMESTAMP

2) Also, how to dynamically read and store data from CSV file located in a folder into MySQL? (if I can read and store it once a day)

Comment: see this tool for windows http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=import_textfile

Comment: Thank you, I will try this one but i do not think that it could be configured to import data automatically for example daily in a particular hour!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some string processing on that field in the CVS to turn it into something that would play well with the temporal data types that MySQL provides. You could use some programming language such as python or perl to accomplish this.

You can use a [cronjob](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html), if on a UNIX-based system to schedule an import of the modified CSV with mysqlimport. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235063/mysql-import-csv-data-ignore-some-csv-columns) for some helpful information on mysqlimport and choosing which fields to insert into the table.

```
mysqlimport --local --columns=@x,B,@x,D,@x,F --ignore-lines=1 --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=\, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n db_name file_name.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Ian. regarding my first question do you mean i need to read the NTP time field from CSV file, convert it then store it to MySQL? How can i do this? I am using VB.Net how can i combine converting the field + automatically storing the CSV file into MySQL